# Login problem after failed update from 14.04

Tags: package-management

I have tried to update my Ubuntu 14.04 to wily wolf but somehow It failed and I restored my factory Ubuntu i.e.,14.04. Now I can't login to my desktop and every time I login it returns to the same page. I also can't access terminal from my login page. Cntlr+alt+ f2 and other keys are not working for me. I can access terminal from guest account but can't do much as guest user has no authority.please help.
I know little about Ubuntu. I appreciate your Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really messed something up bad.  Try this:

1. Boot from Live DVD/USB
2. Mount your `/` partition if not already mounted
3. Copy all your files from your old installation onto another drive (preferably an external USB)
4. Reinstall Ubuntu 16.04, with a clean install
5. Copy all your files back into the new installation.

That should do it.  Without more information I can't tell you what to do other than recover data and reinstall.